# Pyomo running ploblem even with abstractmodel

Tags: python, pyomo

I am new to the pyomo model. I closely followed the tutorial on pyomo documentation and tried to create an AbstractModel with the following code in abstract1.py1.

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

model.m = Param(within = NonNegativeIntegers)
model.n = Param(within = NonNegativeIntegers)

model.I = RangeSet(1, model.m)
model.J = RangeSet(1, model.n)

model.a = Param(model.I, model.J)
model.b = Param(model.I)
model.c = Param(model.J)

# the next line declares a variable indexed by the set J
model.x = Var(model.J, domain=NonNegativeReals)


def obj_expression(model):
    return summation(model.c, model.x)

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

#Declaration of constraint
def ax_constraint_rule(model, i):
    # return the expression for the constraint for i
    return sum(model.a[i,j] * model.x[j] for j in model.J) >= model.b[i]


# the next line creates one constraint for each member of the set model.I
model.AxbConstraint = Constraint(model.I, rule=ax_constraint_rule)
```

Then I created data in AMPL format precisely what is in the example in abstract1.dat.

```
# one way to input the data in AMPL format
# for indexed parameters, the indexes are given before the value

param m := 1 ;
param n := 2 ;

param a :=
1 1 3
1 2 4
;

param c:=
1 2
2 3
;

param b := 1 1 ;
```

Then I tried to run the model through Anaconda  command prompt as follows. 
(base) D:\PostDocResearch\Python>pyomo solve abstract1.py abstract1.dat --solver=glpk
Unfortunately, I encountered the following error message.

```
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
[    0.00] Creating model
[    0.02] Pyomo Finished
ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
        'AbstractModel' object has no attribute 'a'
errorcode: 1
retval: None
```

Later I got like this

```
 (base) D:\PostDocResearch\Python>pyomo solve abstract1.py abstract1.dat --solver=glpk
[    0.00] Setting up Pyomo environment
[    0.00] Applying Pyomo preprocessing actions
[    0.80] Creating model
[    0.82] Applying solver
[    0.89] Processing results
    Number of solutions: 1
    Solution Information
      Gap: 0.0
      Status: feasible
      Function Value: 0.666666666666666
    Solver results file: results.yml
[    0.89] Applying Pyomo postprocessing actions
[    0.89] Pyomo Finished
errorcode: 0
retval: instance: <pyomo.core.base.PyomoModel.ConcreteModel object at 0x000001CCDE0EF818>
local:
    time_initial_import: 0.799086332321167
    usermodel: <module 'abstract1' from 'D:\\PostDocResearch\\Python\\abstract1.py'>
options: <pyutilib.misc.config.ConfigDict object at 0x000001CCDE0B7408>
results: {'Problem': [{'Name': 'unknown', 'Lower bound': 0.666666666666667, 'Upper bound': 0.666666666666667, 'Number of objectives': 1, 'Number of constraints': 2, 'Number of variables': 3, 'Number of nonzeros': 3, 'Sense': 'minimize'}], 'Solver': [{'Status': 'ok', 'Termination condition': 'optimal', 'Statistics': {'Branch and bound': {'Number of bounded subproblems': 0, 'Number of created subproblems': 0}}, 'Error rc': 0, 'Time': 0.04153299331665039}], 'Solution': [OrderedDict([('number of solutions', 1), ('number of solutions displayed', 1)]), {'Gap': 0.0, 'Status': 'feasible', 'Message': None, 'Problem': {}, 'Objective': {'OBJ': {'Value': 0.666666666666666}}, 'Variable': {'x[1]': {'Value': 0.333333333333333}, 'x[2]': {'Value': 0.0}}, 'Constraint': {}}]}
```

Could anybody help me in figuring out?

Thanks

Comment: I just ran you abstract model with cbc solver and it works fine.  Perhaps on your first run you typo'ed the name of the data file or something.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff H. It runs now but I could not stop the messages after `error code.` Anither thing I  could not install the `cbc` compiler as well.